# Beautiful soup question

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to fetch specific rows in an HTML document

The rows have the following attributes set: bgcolor and vallign

Here is a snippet of the HTML table:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr bgcolor="#f01234" valign="top">
        <!--- td's follow ... -->
      </tr>
      <tr bgcolor="#c01234" valign="top">
        <!--- td's follow ... -->
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I've had a very quick look at [BS's documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method%3a%20findAll%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20%2a%2akwargs%29). Its not clear what params to pass to findAll to match the rows I want.

Does anyone know what tp bass to findAll() to match the rows I want?

Comment: Modified question in light of previous struggles by others. Now using BeautifulSoup

Comment: Please make title of your question more specific.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use regex to parse html. Use a html parser

```
import lxml.html
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(your_html)
result = doc.xpath("//tr[(@bgcolor='#f01234' or @bgcolor='#c01234') "
    "and @valign='top']")
print result
```

That will extract all tr elements that match from your html, you can do further operation with them like change text, attribute value, extract, search further...

Obligatory link:

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: Ok, now that you changed your question from regex to `BeautifulSoup`, my answer stands as an example to do with `lxml.html`. I think it is way better than `BeautifulSoup`.

Comment: Oops. Modified question to use BeautifulSoup instead. I already use BS with some of my scripts but never heard of lxml module. Do you know what to pass to BS to fetch the rows (I'm a bit hesitant to install/learn yet another library)

Comment: @skyeagle: Well, I dumped `BeautifulSoup` long ago for `lxml.html` as it is way faster and **supports xpath!!!** so, this answer is better left here as a hint.

Comment: Also, `BeautifulSoup` is unmaintained

Comment: AFAIK, BeautifulSoup does better with bad HTML (at least, that's what it's designed for). I've not tried using xpath, but I like BeautifulSoup's easy `soup.body.h1` style navigation.

Comment: @Thomas K: `lxml.html` is better than `BeautifulSoup` for bad html. You can use that same style of navigation by using `lxml.objectify` but I don't recommend it, since just using xpath is easier and simpler.

Comment: @nosklo: Yet the documentation for lxml.html specifically suggests BeautifulSoup as a parser for really bad html: http://codespeak.net/lxml/lxmlhtml.html#really-broken-pages (and I'd have to disagree that xpath is easier. More powerful, maybe.)

Answer (score 4):

Something like

> soup.findAll('tr', attrs={'bgcolor':
>   re.compile(r'#f01234|#c01234'),
>   'valign': 'top'})